# Erro de sintaxe no for?

Tags: c#, for

Erro: (only assignment call increment decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement)

Não entendo por que está dando esse erro, sendo que a variável é do tipo int...

```
int deQuantidade = 0, ateQuantidade = 0;
string tipo = "";

deQuantidade = Convert.ToInt32(txtDe.Text);
ateQuantidade = Convert.ToInt32(txtAte.Text);
tipo = Convert.ToString(cmbTipo.SelectedIndex);

for (deQuantidade ; deQUantidade < ateQuantidade; deQuantidade++)
{
```

Erro apresentado:

> only assignment call increment decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: Por mais que vocês tenha iniciado a variavel acima tem que passar valor dentro do for
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for

Comment: Existiria algum jeito de fazer isso com apenas essas variáveis? Ou teria que realmente criar outra só para servir como inicializador do for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Antes de tudo... [Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for). Obrigado [@Krismorte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/38251/krismorte) pelo [comentário da documentação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/271995/algu%c3%a9m-pode-me-dar-uma-ajuda-super-r%c3%a1pida-do-porque-acontece-isso-no-la%c3%a7o-de-rep#comment556821_271995)

#### Entendendo o que aconteceu

O erro está no uso do `for`. O `for` consiste de 3 campos (opcionais): atribuição inicial, comparação, incremento. No primeiro campo, você não realizou nenhuma operação de atribuição, apenas colocou o nome da variável.

Isso se aplica na maioria das linguagens que compartilham a sintaxe do `for` tradicional do C. Algumas linguagens tem sintaxe para `for-each` (outra expressão de laço). Outras linguagens permitem que no primeiro campo seja também declarada variável, mas C-ANSI89 não permite.

#### Tá, mas como corrigir?

> Obrigado ao [@Isac](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/82711/isac) por perceber que o valor iniciado era da leitura do texto, não 0

Você poderia iniciar o valor `int deQuantidade = Convert.ToInt32(txtDe.Text)` no primeiro campo do `for`:

```
for (int deQuantidade = Convert.ToInt32(txtDe.Text); deQuantidade < ateQuantidade; deQuantidade++) {
  // ...
```

Esse campo, por sinal, pode ser usado para múltiplas inicializações (separadas por vírgulas `,`):

```
for (int deQuantidade = Convert.ToInt32(txtDe.Text), int ateQuantidade = Convert.ToInt32(txtAte.Text); deQuantidade < ateQuantidade; deQuantidade++) {
  // ...
```

Ou então, mantendo a estrutura de declaração anterior ao laço (mas não inicializando a variável):

```
int deQuantidade;
// ...

for (deQuantidade = Convert.ToInt32(txtDe.Text); deQuantidade < ateQuantidade; deQuantidade++) {
  // ...
```

Ou então, mantendo a estrutura de inicialização anterior ao laço:

```
int deQuantidade = 0;
// ...
deQuantidade = Convert.ToInt32(txtDe.Text);
// ...

for (; deQuantidade < ateQuantidade; deQuantidade++) {
  // ...
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Jefferson ^-^

Answer (score -2):

Tenta fazer a estrutura do for dessa forma, pois a variavel deQuantidade dentro do for, se torna uma variável local

*

```
for (deQuantidade = 0; deQuantidade < ateQuantidade; deQuantidade++){
}
```

*